# Учебная задача. Вывести на печать список кодов, и отдельно на следующей строке один из этих кодов

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, циклы

Вот код создания кодов (простите за тавтологию):

```
m = int(input())
counter = 0

for a in range(1, 10):
    for b in range(1, 10):
        for c in range(1, 10):
            for d in range(1, 10):
                if a<b and c>d and a*b+c*d == m:
                    print(f'{a}{b}{c}{d}', end = ' ')
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что надо - каким-то образом - получившиеся значения добавить в пустой список и потом вывести на печать (к примеру) значение с третьим индексом? Каким образом это сделать?

Comment: Приведите в вопросе пример нужной печати. Что за задачу вы решаете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю вы это имеете в виду

```
from random import randint


m = int(input())
counter = 0
list = []

for a in range(1, 10):
    for b in range(1, 10):
        for c in range(1, 10):
            for d in range(1, 10):
                if a < b and c > d and a * b + c * d == m:
                    list.append(f'{a}{b}{c}{d}')
                    print(f'{a}{b}{c}{d}', end = ' ')

print('\n' + list[randint(0, (len(list) - 1))])
```

Чтобы вывести 3-ий индекс

```
print('\n' + list[3])
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: print('\n' + list[3]) - да, это то, что я искал, а
print('\n' + list[randint(0, (len(list) - 1))]) - как расшифровать эту команду? Она вывела один из кодов из середины.

Comment: Это функция выводит случайный элементы из списка, можете её заменить на 
print('\n' + list[3])
Если вам нужен 3 элемент

Comment: Спасибо! Быстро, четко и по существу )

Comment: Не используйте питоновское имя `list` для названия переменной, не нужно так делать.